# CCLabelTTF incorrectly positioned

Tags: cocos2d-x, cclabelttf

I am having some trouble with cocos2dx (windows-ver. cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.12.0) CCLabelTTF. Whichever label having string-with-spaces, the label is moving upwards by few pixels.

Here is the basic code I used to display two labels (with and without spaces) at the same position. [This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae65G.jpg) shows how it is displayed.

```
CCLabelTTF *label0 = CCLabelTTF::labelWithString( "This is a", GAME_FONT, 20 );
addChild( label0 );
label0->setPosition( ccp( SCR_W / 2, SCR_H / 2 ) );

CCLabelTTF *label1 = CCLabelTTF::labelWithString( "string", GAME_FONT, 20 );
addChild( label1 );
label1->setPosition( ccp( SCR_W / 2, SCR_H / 2 ) );
```

The project is working fine on Mac for iOS. I noticed the bug while trying to port it for windows. It is too late for me to update to a new cocos2dx SDK, as it involves API changes.

Comment: Have you tried this with different fonts? Could be an issue with the font itself.

Comment: Tried with 3 different fonts, but same displacement with every font.

Comment: Try in a new project with this particular cocos2d-x version just to verify this is a cocos2d-x issue. If it is, try verifying the issue in a newer cocos2d-x version. If it's gone there, you may want to upgrade or at least try to locate and cherrypick the corresponding fix.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I downloaded the latest cocos2dx sdk and was surprised to see that the issue is still there. Could this possibly be related to the simulator ? I don't have a device right now. Going to get a device soon and check in it.

Comment: certainly, always verify issues on a device

Comment: I had the same issue, see here: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/35477 . We decided to use instead LabelBMFont in the end.

Comment: Even I used CCLabelBMFont instead and it solved the displacement issue and a bunch of associated crashes. Thanks everyone for replies !

Answer (score 1):

```
you can create label such type. try it
 CCLabelTTF *lbl_Question=CCLabelTTF::create("23", "mvboli.ttf", 36, CCSize(400, 0),       kCCTextAlignmentCenter, kCCVerticalTextAlignmentCenter);
```